# How do I disable hardware detection during PXE boot?

Tags: boot, system-installation, hardware-compatibility, kickstart, pxe

I'm atttempting to install centOS 6.5 on a new dell machine through PXE boot. The PXE boot works fine for other PCs, just the new workstations are problematic. The PXE boot hangs on "Detecting Hardware" indefinately (I let it go for an hour without change). During a normal install at the "Boot:" menu I'd be able to put in 'noprobe' to skip hardware detection, but during a PXE boot a "Boot:" prompt appears, which does not behave the same way (it looks for an image based on the text put in ex:

Boot: noprobe

Image 'noprobe' does not exist

Boot: linux dd

Image 'linux' does not exist

[linux dd is only there as an example, I do not need it])

My guess is that there is something about the hardware that's throwing off the installation, as it is quite different from the old machines that work fine.

I'm wondering:

a) is there a method by which I can get more information about what the installer is attempting to detect? (like a play by play [determining cpuid.....Xeon x86_64 determining RAM....128 GB ect.)

b) how do I use additional boot options in conjunction with PXE? **EDIT**: Appending to initrd.img seems to read in the boot options

c) is there another method to skip hardware detection? **EDIT**: Skipping the hardware detection seems to prevent the machine from downloading the KS file later (I spose that's to be expected), so it doesn't help much.

d) if I do a CD install (assuming it would work), and export a KS from that installation, would it resolve the hardware detection issues for identical machines?

Comment: I believe it should be something like this. `linux all-generic-ide irqpoll pci=nommconf`

Comment: @Ramesh could you please explain what that is attempting to do, or provide a resource that does?

Comment: recently I was trying some USB installation and I stumbled upon this option. 
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=167991

Comment: However, if you just google that option, you could find more sources as well.

Comment: @Ramesh That command doesn'r seem to change anything, install still hangs on 'detecting hardware...'